# Why is the max number coming out to 9?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm waving the white flag on this one. I have a separate file txt file which contains the number list. What I am trying to grasp is why the max number is coming out to 9 every time?

```
def main():

    writeFile()
    numbers = readFile()
    statFile(numbers)


def writeFile():

    import random
    outfile = open('numbers.dat', 'w')

    for i in range(100):

        number = random.randint(1, 1001)
        outfile.write(str(number)+ '\n')

    outfile.close()

    return print("All numbers have been generated and written to file.")


def readFile():

    infile = open('numbers.dat', 'r')

    return (infile.read())

    infile.close()


def statFile(numbers):

    return print("The largest number is: ", max(numbers))


main()
```

Comment: `infile.close()` is dead code here. Nothing after return statements runs in a function

Answer (score 0):

There is a delimeter with each line "\n" which is causing this issue. Below change will give u  correct answer:

```
numbers = readFile().split("\n")
```

Also file.read() will read the whole file content in the numbers variable, not as List/Array.

Answer (score 0):

because numbers in your code is a string of integer values. and the max function returns the max alphabetical value of any string which is 9.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently finding the max *character of a string*.

`infile.read()` doesn't return numeric values, and it doesn't split individual lines

You need to read the file into a list of numbers

```
def readFile():
    with open('numbers.dat') as infile:
        return (int(line) for line in infile)
```